# Tags [expandable] and [expendable]

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I  noticed that someone had confused the words EXPANDABLE and EXPENDABLE and used the wrong tag.

To avoid confusion I added a description for the [expandable](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expandable) tag.

However, I'm not sure if the best course of action now is to write a description for the [expendable](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expendable) tag, or just delete it. It may actually have value considering the context in which it is used: expendable versus re-usable spacecraft and components.

Just wanted to see if there was a consensus.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure either really adds much value to the site, especially since they are so easily confused. Expandable is only used on one question.